# Is integration well defined on polynomials in the circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

I want to see if there is a well defined map
$$\int_0^\theta\text{d}\theta:\frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle}\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle}.$$
I am starting my study of algebraic geometry and I have found this puzzling. This is related to another post [Polar coordinates for polynomials on the circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793983/polar-coordinates-for-polynomials-on-the-circle).

I have tried going into polar coordinates but there is no simple expression for an integral of the form
$$\int_0^\theta \text{d}\theta\,\cos(\theta)^n\sin(\theta)^m.$$
On the other hand, in complex coordinates one has
$$\int_\mathcal{C}\text{d}z\,z^n\bar{z}^m=\begin{cases}i r^{n+m}\theta, & 1+n-m=0\\
\frac{z^{n+1/2}\bar{z}^{m-1/2}-(z\bar{z})^{(n+m)/2}}{1+n+m},&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
In here $\mathcal{C}$ is the arc in the circle of radius $r$ between $0$ and $\theta$. Thus, in $\mathbb{C}[z,\bar{z}]$ this doesn't even seem to be well defined. For example, in the case $1+n-m=0$ it does not even yield a function.

Comment: Just so you know, there *are* relatively simple formulas for your integral of sines and cosines using multiple angle formulas. It's completely unclear to me what relation this has to the complex integral you define later, and furthermore why you want to start your study of algebraic geometry this way. Integration of differential forms on varieties leads quickly to residues and duality, which requires a fair bit more setup in the algebraic geometry world than in the algebraic topology world. Depending on your motivations, it may behoove you to spend more time building your base of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It at least does induce a well defined operator on some polynomials. The key is that I did the computation in polar coordinates wrong. The relevant computation is
$$\int_0^\theta\text{d}\theta\,z^n\bar{z}^m=\frac{z^n\bar{z}^m}{i(n-m)}\in\mathbb{C}[z,\bar{z}],$$
as long as $n\neq m$. Since taking the real part of a complex number is linear and every real polynomial can be obtained by taking the real part of a complex one, this proofs what we needed. The problem of $n\neq m$ in the above computation is solved because on the circle the polynomials $z^n\bar{z}^n$ are in the same equivalence class than $1$.